# How to clear cookies in scrapy?

Tags: python, cookies, scrapy

By default, scrapy stores and passes cookies along requests. But how do I access or clear the stored cookies at certain point in the spider? Thanks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to set cookies to a specific request use [request cookies field](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) for example from docs:

```
request_with_cookies = Request(url="http://www.example.com",
                               cookies={'currency': 'USD', 'country': 'UY'})
```

do access request cookies:

```
request.headers.getlist('Cookie')
```

response cookies:

```
response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')
```

for more details see [cookies middleware](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/downloadermiddleware/cookies.py)

Answer (score 7):

one way to avoid the cookies on your next requests would be to use the `meta` argument `dont_merge_cookies`:

```
 Request(url, meta={'dont_merge_cookies': True})
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite clearing them, but [setting `COOKIES_ENABLED` to false in scrapy settings](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std%3asetting-COOKIES_ENABLED) will prevent them from being used.