# Clear cookies on scrapy completely instead of changing them

Tags: python, cookies, scrapy

I noticed that I sometimes get blocked while scraping because of a session cookie being used on too many pages.
Is there a way to simply clear all cookies completely during crawling to get back to the initial state of the crawler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear cookies in scrapy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924220/how-to-clear-cookies-in-scrapy)

Comment: Thanks! I saw this thread but it is explaining how to set new cookies, not how to clear them on already yielded requests.

Comment: Have you read the second answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21930089/1534704

Comment: Yes. Setting COOKIES_ENABLED = False would completely prevent scrapy from storing the cookies.

In my case, I need the cookies to scrape but I'd like to renew them when my IP gets blacklisted (simultaneously with the IP change).

Comment: Not an expert on the subject but setting new cookies (with the same names but different values) is not the same as *renewing them*? Anyway, maybe the answers on the other question don't fit your case, but the question itself seems clearly a duplicate to me... Maybe you could elaborate more your question to avoid this duplicity. Idk, just trying to help... :)

Answer (score 0):

Facing the similar situation myself. I can get away easily here, but one idea that I have is to subclass CookieMiddleware and then write a method to tweak jar variable directly. It's dirty, but maybe is worth consideration.

Another option would be to write a feature request to at least have a function to clear the cookies. Can easily take another year to implement, if deemed needed at all, I don't particularly trust scrapy devs here.

Just occured to me, that you can use your own cookiejar meta, and if you want to return to the clean state, you simply use different value (something like incrementing an integer would do).